# How can I create a confidence band in anychart?

Tags: reactjs, anychart

[image]

I want to achieve something similar to the photo attached. Also, this has to be a scatter line chart. I tried using two area charts to create a similar effect, but it is not possible to create a area chart with a scatter chart.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share the data for the chart that you need to display? AnyChart scatter plot by itself doesn't support range area (as of April 2022) but there are some ways to get around it with certain data sets.